# В мобильной версии сайта появляется отступ справа. Как найти и убрать?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Всем привет!
И снова проблема. **rpsu.zzz.com.ua** - макет на хостинге. В мобильной версии справа появляется отступ и соответственно горизонтальная прокрутка. Проверял и никаких вылезающих элементов не обнаружил. 
Прошу не обращать внимание на корявость верстки, а прошу помочь найти косяк, который мешает красоте.
Мутки с overflow прошу оставить на экстренный случай.
Спасибо!

Comment: .row делает отрицательные отступы (выходит за границы родителя) ... нужен родитель с `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: тоесть overflow: hidden; дать классу container?

Comment: можно просто написать .row { margin: 0 !important; } и всё будет ок

Comment: не вариант. сразу поплыла верстка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.container {
  max-width: 1150px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Для разрешений экранов меньше 1150px включительно делать след. (добавить в css)

```
@media(max-width: 1150px) {
  .container {max-width: 100%; padding: 0 15px;}
}
```

Comment: увы не работает

Comment: попробуй вместо padding: inherit; padding: 0 15px